# Sorting DataTable string column, but with null/empty at the bottom

Tags: c#, vb.net, sorting, datatable, gridview-sorting

I need to sort a DataTable or DataGridView by a column that is a string value, but with null/empty values at the BOTTOM when sorting ASCENDING.

The DataTable is NOT populated by a SQL statement, so no order by.

If I do

```
DataGridView1.Sort(New RowComparer(System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending))
```

then it throws an exception, saying that the DataGridView is DataBound, which is correct, but doesn't help me, and I want to keep it databound.

It's .NET 2.0, which means no LINQ available!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in some cases you could do this if you have another extra column in your table:

```
SELECT completed, completed IS NULL AS isnull
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY isnull DESC, completed DESC
```

Edit: 
Like this in VB.NET

```
        For Each srSearchResult In srcSearchResultCollection

            Try
                dr = dt.NewRow()
                dr("cn") = srSearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("cn").Value
                dr("Account") = srSearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("sAMAccountName").Value
                dr("Nachname") = srSearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("sn").Value
                dr("Vorname") = srSearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("givenname").Value
                dr("Mail") = srSearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("mail").Value
                dr("HomeDirectory") = srSearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("homedirectory").Value
                dr("LogonScript") = srSearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("scriptPath").Value

                dr("IsNull") = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr("Nachname").ToString())

                dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        Next srSearchResult
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "IsNull ASC, Nachname ASC"
```

Comment: @Waqas Raja: It's dirty, but it does work ! Funny, I somehow I always seem to miss the simplest solutions.

Comment: Cool, then you can set my answer as answer ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Davide Piras has a good solution, however there is another simplest solution I have

Add a new column and do it in just one line

```
// just, add a new column
ActualDataTable.Columns.Add("NullEmptyCheck", typeof(int), "ColumnNameToSort is Null OR ColumnNameToSort = ''");

// apply sort expression
ActualDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "NullEmptyCheck asc, ColumnNameToSort asc";
// pass datasource to grid
MyGridView.DataSource = ActualDataTable.DefaultView;
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

even if the DataTable you bind to the user interface control DataGridView is not populated via SQL, you can still sort it using a DataView, you can do something like this:

```
DataView myView = myDataTable.DefaultView;
myView,Sort = "yourColumnName ASC";
```

then you do your binding.

how does it work? Are the null values in the top or in the bottom?

Comment: yeah but it will not put Null/empty values at bottom.

Comment: Sure, that's exactly what I have done, just that you didn't quite realize the point of the question is to get null/empty at the bottom, which is exactly what doesn't happen that way.

Comment: I have added another answer with a possible solution, in this answer I just wanted to point out how to apply the sort to the DataTable and not to the UI control.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a way to achieve this in `.NET 4+`, here is a example :

```
DataTable orderedDataTable = sourceDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                            .OrderByDescending(row => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME")))
                                            .ThenBy(row => row.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME"))
                                            .CopyToDataTable();
```

This will place `null` values at the end of the table (note that both empty and white spaces strings will have the same rank) and then order the requested column in ascending order.